# Split one row into multiple rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column in a dataframe like the one below, each row contains multiple countries separated by `,`

```
df <- data.frame(
                  countries = c(
                                "UK , Spain , Germany , Italy , Netherlands" , 
                                "UK , Canada , AUS , China" , 
                                "Spain , AUS , Italy , Russia"
                                )
                )
```

This is how data looks like

```
                   countries
1 UK , Spain , Germany , Italy , Netherland
2                 UK , Canada , AUS , China
3              Spain , AUS , Italy , Russia
```

How can we transform this to be something like below?

```
  countries
1   UK
2   Spain
3   Germany
4   Italy
5   Netherlands
6   UK
7   Canada
8   AUS
9   China
10  Spain
11  AUS
12  Italy
13  Russia
```

Comment: In case you have more column there, you could also do `library(splitstackshape) ; cSplit(df, "countries", direction = "long")`

Comment: Another option is `data.frame(countries=scan(text=gsub(' ', '', df$countries), what='', sep=','))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just try:

```
data.frame(countries = unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$countries), " , ")))
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use 'separate_rows' from "tidyr" package:

```
df = separate_rows(df,1,sep = ",")
```