# Unnesting related list-columns of different size

Tags: r, list, pivot, unnest

After parsing xml files I have data looking like this:

```
example_df <-  
  tibble(id = "ABC",
         wage_type = "salary",
         name = c("Description","Code","Base",
                  "Description","Code","Base",
                  "Description","Code"),
         value = c("wage_element_1","51B","600",
                   "wage_element_2","51C","740",
                   "wage_element_3","51D"))

example_df 

# A tibble: 8 x 4
  id    wage_type name        value         
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>       <chr>         
1 ABC   salary    Description wage_element_1
2 ABC   salary    Code        51B           
3 ABC   salary    Base        600           
4 ABC   salary    Description wage_element_2
5 ABC   salary    Code        51C           
6 ABC   salary    Base        740           
7 ABC   salary    Description wage_element_3
8 ABC   salary    Code        51D
```

with roughly 1000 different `id`, and each having three possible values for `wage_type`.
I want to change the values in the `name` column into columns.
I have tried to use `pivot` but I am struggling to handle the resulting `list-cols`: since not all `salary` have a `Base`, the resulting list-cols are of different size as below:

```
example_df <- example_df %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id, wage_type),
              names_from = name,
              values_from = value)

example_df

# A tibble: 1 x 5
  id    wage_type Description Code      Base     
  <chr> <chr>     <list>      <list>    <list>   
1 ABC   salary    <chr [3]>   <chr [3]> <chr [2]>
```

So when I try to unnest the cols it throws an error:

```
example_df%>%
  unnest(cols = c(Description,Code,Base))

Error: Can't recycle `Description` (size 3) to match `Base` (size 2).
```

I understand that is because tidyr functions do not recycle, but I could not find a way around this or a `base r`solution to my problem. I have tried to make a df with
`unlist(strsplit(as.character(x))` solution as per [how to split one row into multiple rows in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283873/how-to-split-one-row-into-multiple-rows-in-r) but also ran into a resulting column length issue.

Desired output is as follows:

```
desired_df <- 
  tibble(
    id=c("ABC","ABC","ABC"),
    wage_type=c("salary","salary","salary"),
    Description = c("wage_element_1","wage_element_2","wage_element_3"),
    Code = c("51B","51C","51D"),
    Base = c("600","740",NA))

desired_df

id    wage_type Description    Code  Base 
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>          <chr> <chr>
1 ABC   salary    wage_element_1 51B   600  
2 ABC   salary    wage_element_2 51C   740  
3 ABC   salary    wage_element_3 51D   NA
```

I would love a tidyr solution but any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this approach using `tidyverse` functions. The issue you had was due to how functions manage different rows. So, by creating an id variable like `id2` you can avoid list outputs in your final reshaped data:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
example_df %>% 
  arrange(name) %>%
  group_by(id,wage_type,name) %>%
  mutate(id2=1:n()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=value) %>%
  select(-id2)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  id    wage_type Base  Code  Description   
  <chr> <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>         
1 ABC   salary    600   51B   wage_element_1
2 ABC   salary    740   51C   wage_element_2
3 ABC   salary    NA    51D   wage_element_3
```